# app.currentUser shows null after logging in with Realm React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, realm

I'm trying to implement auth with Realm in my React Native app. I've done the following part and it shows successfull login when i put the correct credentials but when i try to access the current user, it shows null. Here's the current implementation like:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, SafeAreaView, Button, View, TextInput, Alert} from 'react-native';
import Realm from 'realm';

const app= new Realm.App({id : "<your Realm app ID here>"});


const App = () => {


  const [user, setUser] = useState(app.currentUser || null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


const signIn = async () => {
     try {
      const creds = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password);
      const newUser = await app.logIn(creds);
      console.log("Successfully logged in!", app);
      setUser(newUser);
    } catch(err){
      console.error("Failed to log in", err.message);
    }
};
```

why can't i see the current user. How can i overcome this ?

Comment: How are you accessing currentUser? Here? `useState(app.currentUser` and where is it showing null? When you add a breakpoint and step through the code within signIn, what are you seeing? what does `setUser` do?

Comment: As you can see, i'm consoling app after logging in. But it shows empty object. If i don't see anything in app, then obviously app.currentUser is null. So, my question was why i'm not seeing anything in app and how can i access current user. @Jay

Comment: Your console logging `app`. Try this `console.log("Successfully logged in!", newUser.id);`

Comment: yaah with newUser.id i am getting the id. But how do i get the user details from that? @Jay

Comment: Not sure what is meant by 'user details'. All of the info about the user are contained in the user objects properties. See the documentation for those.